# Find the dimension and a basis of the given extension field $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{3})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

How do I find a base?

> Find the dimension and a basis of the given extension field
>   $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{3})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a first step, can you give a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$? And do you know what the degree of the extension is (how many basis elements you're looking for)?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $\sqrt[3]2\notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ is clear. Since $X^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ on $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$, you have $$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)]=3.$$
Also, $X^2-3$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3$ over $\mathbb Q$, and thus

$$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt 3),\mathbb Q]=6.$$
A basis is given by $$\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},(\sqrt[3]{2})^2,\sqrt 3,\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt 3(\sqrt[3]2)^2\}$$

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: I also hate these downvotes without any explanation. Downvoters should have to tell the reason, except if they agree with a previous downvoter who had explained the downvote... But I also think it could have been not purposeful. On the other day, I downvoted my own answer (the downvote didn't keep because it's not possible to vote our own answers) because accidentally I clicked the mouse while hovering the top of the answer, but far aside the triangles. Maybe this method of having the votes on the top will provoke more such errors... By the way, +1